# Angular JS Filter: Why does this remove other LIKE options?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this angular filter;

```
ng-options="option.name as option.name for option in options |
filter: newForm.select2 && {name: '!' + newForm.select2} | 
filter: newForm.select3 && {name: '!' + newForm.select3}
```

Plunker [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/Fx7igqMjPsBQz1vtUlsM?p=preview).

Basically, it removes options from the ng-options if they get selected in either of the other selects.  Issue I am having is it will actually remove options that are LIKE the selected one also.  So, selecting '1' will remove both '1' and '11' from the other options.

How can I make this explicit so it only removes exact matches?

Thanks!

EDIT:  I have tried adding : true to the filter as explained in the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) with no luck either...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switch to using the id's rather than the names. For example, see this [fork of your plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/eBwlo2EerXEIynatEhJd?p=preview).

```
<select ng-model="newForm.select2" 
        ng-options="option.id as option.name for option in options | filter: newForm.select1 && {id: '!' + newForm.select1} | filter: newForm.select3 && {id: '!' + newForm.select3}" 
        class="form-control">
```

Comment: That's it exactly.  Makes sense, should have thought of that. Thanks!